# Error (10327): VHDL error at clkdivider.vhd(27): can't determine definition of operator ""not"" -- found 0 possible definitions

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus

I am still a beginner and I keep getting this error, can anyone help pls?

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity ClkDivider is

port ( clk_in : in STD_LOGIC;
        reset : in STD_LOGIC;
     clk_out : out STD_LOGIC);


end ClkDivider;


architecture behaviour of ClkDivider is


signal counter: integer := 0;


signal temporal: integer range 0 to 499 := 0;


begin 
    clock_divider: process (reset, clk_in) 


     begin

if (reset = '1') then

            temporal <= 0;
            counter <= 0;

        elsif rising_edge(clk_in) then
            if (counter = 499) then
                temporal <= not (temporal);
                counter <= 0;
            else
                counter <= counter + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    clk_out <= temporal;
end behaviour;
```

Comment: I understand, that it is not allowing you to post code only question. It's for a reason. Please format properly.

Comment: I rarely use VHDL but to me the error message says that the `not` operator is not defined for integers.

Answer (score 2):

The `NOT` operator is not defined for integers, you can only use it on formats like `std_logic`, `std_logic_vector`, `signed`, `unsigned`, `bit`, `bit_vector`, ...

Why ?
Because VHDL don't assume any hardware implementation for integers : It can be binary numbers, but it is not mandatory. The synthesiser is free to use any encoding.
For example, your simple counter could be implemented with a linear feedback shift register and it would be smaller and faster (in an ASIC) than a binary adder.

Conversion functions are available in the `IEEE.numeric_std.ALL` library for `integer` <-> `signed`/`unsigned` conversions.

Anyway, there are a few other problems with your code.

- The counter integer has no range, which is bad coding, particularly for synthesisable code.
- `cly_out` is a `std_logic`, temporal is an `integer`, what do you intent to do with  `clk_out <= temporal` ?

Comment: LFSRs are faster in FPGAs too due to the carry chain.